# UIImagePicker can't perform full-screen transition on iOS 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-3.x

I am modifying my iphone app to make it backward compatible with iOS 3.1.3. I allow the user to load images from the photo library. I present the image picker with the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController* content = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
content.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
content.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:content animated:YES];
[content release];
```

This works correctly on ios 4.0+. However, on ios 3.1.3, the image picker never appears, and I get the following warning:

```
Can't perform full-screen transition. The fromViewController's view must be 
within a view that occupies the full screen.
```

The fromViewController in this case is the visible view controller within a navigation controller. The navigation controller is set up in the appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions using the following code segment:

```
MyViewController* root = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:root];
aNavigationController.delegate = self;    
[window addSubview:aNavigationController.view];
```

Prior to attempting to load the image picker, another view controller is presented in the navigation controller. Therefore, at the time the image picker is loaded, two view controllers are in the navigation stack.

Based on another post, I have tried using the root view controller and the navigation controller as the fromViewController (the controller presenting the image picker). The behavior is the same.

I'm wondering if the problem has anything to do with the fact that the navigation controller's modalPresentationStyle cannot be set in iOS 3.1.3. For iOS 3.2+, I set the presentation style to UIModalPresentationFullScreen. I believe this is the default for previous iOS's. However, I'm suspicious simply because the warning I'm getting concerns full-screen views.

Can anyone provide any other suggestions? I have not been able to find any Apple documentation that addresses changes to UIImagePicker or UINavigationController from ios 3.x to 4.0.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do when the view controller is inside a navigation controller is:

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.delegate = self;

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: No luck. I get the same behavior when I present from the navigation controller, the root view controller or the visible view controller.

Comment: @jenonen "Prior to attempting to load the image picker, another view controller is presented in the navigation controller" How do you present that view controller?

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];

Comment: Maybe it's a weird thing that you are presenting a modal view controller at the same time that you are pushing another one. Why don't you try to wait until the second view controller is pushed?

Comment: They aren't happening at the same time. I push the second view controller, and from it, I present the modal view controller. One question I've had is the fact that iOS 3.1.3 cannot specify the modalPresentationStyle. I set this to UModalPresentationFullScreen for iOS 3.2+, but it is supposed to be full screen for prior iOS's.

Comment: Well try without setting the `UIModalPresentationStyle`(That's only for iPad) and see if it works on the 3.1.3.